# ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor timer doesn't fire if another timer event is hanged

Tags: java, threadpool

Consider following code.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class Test {
    private static ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor threadPool = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(0);

    public static void onTimer() {
        System.out.println("onTimer");
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
            }
        }
    }

    public static void onTimer2() {
        System.out.println("onTimer2");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        threadPool.scheduleAtFixedRate(Test::onTimer, 0, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        threadPool.scheduleAtFixedRate(Test::onTimer2, 0, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

There are two timers scheduled at fixed rate, and in the first timer event, the task hangs indefinitely.

Even though the first task hangs, I expect the second timer to fire at specified rate, since it is created using a thread pool that is allowed to create as many threads as it wants.

But, the second timer never fires.

Can someone explain why?

Comment: Because your thread pool size is 0. Increase the thread pool size to 2 or more and try again

Comment: @SangramJadhav 0 is the initial size of the thread pool. According to the documentation, the pool is allowed to grow as it needs.

Comment: @SangramJadhav was about to comment on that, but it seems unrelated. You can schedule multiple concurrent tasks with a pool size initially set to 0.

Comment: @SangramJadhav but you are also right. A size set to `2` will execute the two tasks concurrently even if one of them blocks indefinitely. Weird...

Comment: From the docs: "While this class inherits from ThreadPoolExecutor, a few of the inherited tuning methods are not useful for it. In particular, because it acts as a fixed-sized pool using corePoolSize threads and an unbounded queue, adjustments to maximumPoolSize have no useful effect. **Additionally, it is almost never a good idea to set corePoolSize to zero or use allowCoreThreadTimeOut because this may leave the pool without threads to handle tasks once they become eligible to run. **"

Comment: @Mena never hurts to write such things as an answer...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes too lazy this time :) It seems someone else elaborated and wrote a decent one in my stead though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quote from [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor's javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) explains it I guess

> While this class inherits from ThreadPoolExecutor, a few of the inherited tuning methods are not useful for it. In particular, because it acts as a fixed-sized pool using corePoolSize threads and an unbounded queue, adjustments to maximumPoolSize have no useful effect. Additionally, it is almost never a good idea to set corePoolSize to zero or use allowCoreThreadTimeOut because this may leave the pool without threads to handle tasks once they become eligible to run.

The key part you've missed is that the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor class is "**a fixed-sized pool** using *corePoolSize* threads and an unbounded queue". So it won't produce any extra threads more than *corePoolSize*.

If you're wondering why it actually executes with corePoolSize == 0, here is a code snippet from ThreadPoolExecutor which ensures there would be at least one thread (and the one which prevents more threads started in your case):

```
call order:  
1. java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor#scheduleAtFixedRate 
2. java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor#delayedExecute   
3. java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor#ensurePrestart
            /**
             * Same as prestartCoreThread except arranges that at least one
             * thread is started even if corePoolSize is 0.
             */
            void ensurePrestart() {
                int wc = workerCountOf(ctl.get());
                if (wc < corePoolSize)
                    addWorker(null, true);
                else if (wc == 0) //here's your case
                    addWorker(null, false);
            }
```